# How do I embed an xls file inside a docx file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xls

I have an Excel workbook (.xls) generated by my application, and I want to embed it inside a `XWPFDocument`.

I have searched for documentation on how to do this, but I was only able
to find information on how to access a file that is already embedded.

How can I embed an Excel (.xls) workbook inside of a `XWPFDocument` using Apache POI?

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: I could not find any example either, anyone?

Comment: Did someone find a solution to this question?